# Unable to show the Add-in tab in MSWORD VSTO 2022

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-addins, word-addins, ribbonx

I was trying to build a simple MS WORD add in,
The home ribbon has been added.
I am getting the message box on the Addin Stated but the home ribbon is not showing.
Even I have configured the things as follows.
[image: No errors in the VSTO errors tab, and its running smoothly]

For the Addin settings
[image]

Inside the MS OFFICE Options
[image: The settings for Add in for addin]

[image]

Also I tried to get the logs in the MS WORD UI erros,
I am not getting any errors in MS word application also.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after closing all the windows and restarting, I am able to see the addin in the home section.
[image]